# Simple IF statement not working correctly

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function that checks for a winner in the game Quarto. The game is kind of like connect four or tic tac toe. The game consist of 16 unique piece each having four characteristics. White “W”, Black “B”, Long “L”, Short “S”, Square “R”, Circle “C”, Hollow “H”, Filled “F” So for example,the White Long Circle Hollow piece == “WLCH”. One player selects a piece and the other places that piece on a 16x16 board.  If four characteristics are aligned vertically, horizontally or diagonally the last player to place a piece wins.

At first I thought about using switch statements but apparently you can't use pass in strings, only an interger,char or a enumeration.

So I am trying to us multiple IF statements starting with a four White pieces aligned horizontally in the first row. I thought this would be easy ... however the function determines a winner every time.

This is what I have so far:

```
bool checkWinner(string board[ROWS][COLS])
{

if( (board[0][0]== ("WSHR")||("WTHR")||("WTFR")||("WSHC")||("WTFC")||("WSFR")||("WTHC")||("WTFC"))
    &&(board[0][1]== ("WSHR")||("WTHR")||("WTFR")||("WSHC")||("WTFC")||("WSFR")||("WTHC")||("WTFC"))
    &&(board[0][2]== ("WSHR")||("WTHR")||("WTFR")||("WSHC")||("WTFC")||("WSFR")||("WTHC")||("WTFC"))
    &&(board[0][3]== ("WSHR")||("WTHR")||("WTFR")||("WSHC")||("WTFC")||("WSFR")||("WTHC")||("WTFC")))
    {
        cout << "\nWinner!!!!!\n";
        return true;

    }
return false;
```

}

I added parentheses around every string after the function didn't work the first time.

I know it has to be something simple but I can't see it, I would appreciate any help on this problem.

Comment: I should mention that the 2D array board is 4x4 and contains 16 empty strings. When I insert strings that do not contain "W" the function still returns true, in fact it returns true every time.

Comment: Instead of strings you can number the possible pieces from 0 through 15. Instead of listing all possible combinations you can use loops to search through the board array. Instead of a function that checks and outputs a message, you can use a function that just checks and a returns a boolean (which is much easier to reuse in a graphical user interface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simple and mayankTUM has already answered it, but you can do it with the power of the STL.
I wrote a sample to show you :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

#define ROWS 1
#define COLS 4

using namespace std;

bool checkWinner(string board[ROWS][COLS])
{
    list<string> l;
    l.push_back("WSHR");
    l.push_back("WTHR");
    l.push_back("WTFR");
    l.push_back("WSHC");
    l.push_back("WTFC");
    l.push_back("WSFR");
    l.push_back("WTHC");
    l.push_back("WTFC");

    bool hasWon = true;
    for(int col = 0; col < COLS && hasWon; ++col)
    for(int row = 0; row < ROWS && hasWon; ++row)
    {
        hasWon &= find(l.begin(), l.end(), board[row][col]) != l.end();
    }

    if(hasWon)
    {
        cout << "Winner!!!!!" << endl;
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    string board[ROWS][COLS] = {"WSHR", "WTHR", "WTFR", "WSHC"};
    string board2[ROWS][COLS] = {"WSHR", "WTHR", "WZFR", "WSHC"};

    cout << "board has to be true : " << boolalpha << checkWinner(board) << endl;
    cout << "board2 has to be false : " << boolalpha << checkWinner(board2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the result is :
*Winner!!!!!

board has to be true : true

board2 has to be false : false*

The code is pretty obvious, so I think I don't need to explain it, but feel free to comment if you need more precisions.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are trying to use the if statement might be wrong. You are doing an OR of strings rather than the condition itself. Try this.

```
bool checkWinner(string board[ROWS][COLS])
{

if( (board[0][0]== ("WSHR")||board[0][0]==("WTHR")||board[0][0]==("WTFR")||board[0][0]==("WSHC")||board[0][0]==("WTFC")||board[0][0]==("WSFR")||board[0][0]==("WTHC")||board[0][0]==("WTFC"))
    &&(board[0][1]== ("WSHR")||board[0][1]==("WTHR")||board[0][1]==("WTFR")||board[0][1]==("WSHC")||board[0][1]==("WTFC")||board[0][1]==("WSFR")||board[0][1]==("WTHC")||board[0][1]==("WTFC"))
    &&(board[0][2]== ("WSHR")||board[0][2]==("WTHR")||board[0][2]==("WTFR")||board[0][2]==("WSHC")||board[0][2]==("WTFC")||board[0][2]==("WSFR")||board[0][2]==("WTHC")||board[0][2]==("WTFC"))
    &&(board[0][3]== ("WSHR")||board[0][3]==("WTHR")||board[0][3]==("WTFR")||board[0][3]==("WSHC")||board[0][3]==("WTFC")||board[0][3]==("WSFR")||board[0][3]==("WTHC")||board[0][3]==("WTFC")))
    {
        cout << "\nWinner!!!!!\n";
        return true;

    }
return false;
}
```